# Link to intent - is it possible?

Tags: android, android-intent, applinks

Is there any way to create a link, that will call an intent? It is good to create intents in application and call it from there, but what if I want to pass an intent throw link, for example in message or put it on website.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `Deep Linking`

Deep Linking is concept by using we can open our application from Hyper Links , from Emails , Messages and from webpages ,Also able to pass some values with Intent for further uses on Next Activity to be open as Input Value .

For this we have to make our Activity Browse-able and Need Define host and Schema for that , So Android System match with all available Browse-able Activities and start that Activity.

Please find complete information in below link:

https://developers.helpshift.com/android/deep-linking/

Comment: The problem is to link an intent to an existing application. It has an intent-configuration, but in the doc, it is only information, how to create and call intent from another app. And I want to call it whenever I open a specific link.

Comment: Code available in my Answer is for your application not for other application , As I wrote in my answer , You have to create one actvity in your application which you want to open when you click on any web link from anya whare in your mobile phone , your link must be contain  myscheme://example.com/?faqid=95 -  here myscheme -> http/https and example,com -> host  , code is fore handling upcoming intent clicked from web links .

Comment: please find more information in this links - https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Comment: So, if author of an application has not done activities for links, there is no way to call it's ident without an application with hardcoded intent call?

Comment: Yes Android system  need schema and host  to browse appropriate activity within all installed application , just like when we want to share any content through Intent and all sharing application are listed in Chooser Dialog .Or when we want to open any web URL all available web browsers are listed into chooser.